# Excel: Cannot edit text just deletes the whole thing

Tags: excel, office365, erase

I am new to excel and every time I try to edit text in excel by double clicking the cell or press the back space button when I make an error it just deletes the whole thing and I need to retype everything.

I was wondering if there was any way to turn this off.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try pressing ``ESC`` or undo ``CTRL+z``.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there no way to turn this off. When you want to edit text in a cell, you need to first select the cell by single clicking on it. Any contents in the cell will display in the formula bar located above the spreadsheet. Click anywhere you need to in the formula bar to edit text. If you delete or backspace on the cell accidentally, you can `CTRL+z` to undo.

If you do not see the formula bar, click on View tab in the menu ribbon and make sure the Formula Bar option is checked.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out either. However, when I added one table to another it it no longer erases the text when I edit. Thanks anyways!